# Cant open nginx.conf file via sudo mate command in Linode Ubuntu 10.04 box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nginx, linode

when we run `sudo mate /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` we get two different errors

`sudo: unable to resolve host myhost`

`sudo: mate: command not found`

how can we get this file to open? `sudo mate` wont open it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mate` is a command installed by Textmate, which is an OS X app, not a Linux one. You need to use something like `emacs` or `vim` or `nano` to edit files on your Linode instance.

Comment: we're following [this nginx guide](http://www.modrails.com/videos/passenger_nginx.mov) how should we go about grabbing that file?

Comment: in the [nginx deploy guide](http://www.modrails.com/videos/passenger_nginx.mov) what do we replace `rails_env development` with in order to send it live? at 2:26.

Comment: you're best asking a new question, rails deployment isn't my area :)

Answer (score 0):

The first error is because you haven't defined your hostname properly, if you wish to know how to do that you can find out [here](http://library.linode.com/getting-started#sph_set-the-hostname).

Second is because you don't have mate installed, try running the following instead:

```
sudo nano /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```